# Error in Join on a relation ManyToOne. Using QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring, join, spring-data, querydsl

I have problems using join with QUeryDSL. I'm trying to receive a list of "Clube" which has a ManyToOne relation with "Federacao".

Could someone help me?

Thanks.

The relation is between the classes below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "federacoes")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idgen", sequenceName = "federacoes_id_federacao_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id_federacao"))
public class Federacao extends AbstractEntity{

private String sigla;
private String uf;
private String nome;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "clubes")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idgen", sequenceName = "clubes_id_clube_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id_clube"))
public class Clube extends AbstractEntity{

private Federacao federacao;
...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_federacao")
@Column(name = "federacao")
public Federacao getFederacao() {
    return federacao;
}
...
}
```

I'm using QueryDSL and in the repository class which extends QueryDslRepositorySupport I'm doing this:

```
...
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

private static final QClube qClube = QClube.clube;
private static final QFederacao qFederacao = QFederacao.federacao;

@Override
public List<Clube> findAll(FilterClubeDTO filterClubeDTO) {

JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
    return query.from(qClube)
        .innerJoin(qFederacao).on(qClube.federacao.eq(qFederacao))
    .orderBy(qClube.id.desc())
    .list(qClube);

}
```

I'm receiving this exception:

```
2016-04-12 12:32:38.485 ERROR 2853 --- [ qtp36627152-15] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        :  Path expected for join!


org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select clube
from br.com.cbfm.core.models.Clube clube
inner join Federacao federacao with clube.federacao = federacao
order by clube.id desc]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select clube
from br.com.cbfm.core.models.Clube clube
inner join Federacao federacao with clube.federacao = federacao
order by clube.id desc]
```

Comment: Try with removing the `@Column` annotation from : 

`@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_federacao")
@Column(name = "federacao")
public Federacao getFederacao() {
    return federacao;
}`

And keep it like this :

`@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_federacao")
public Federacao getFederacao() {
    return federacao;
}`

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected:

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);
    return query.from(qClube)
        .innerJoin(qClube.federacao, qFederacao)
    .orderBy(qClube.id.desc())
    .list(qClube);
```

Comment: Hey Meiko. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I tried it before. I have this exception. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:408)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3903)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3689)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)

Comment: in your question you wrote: ..."Clube" which has a ManyToOne relation with "Federacao".... But i cannot see a `ManyToOne` annotation... only a `OneToOne`

Comment: I'm sorry @Meiko . I was just testing but I have the same problem in ManyToOne and OneToOne. I just correct on the question.

Comment: I assume a problem with the defined Entities and no query dsl related problem now... maybe you could show the complete definitions...

Comment: Hey Meiko. If is possible you can see my code in my github. I commited there this code in a provisory way. When I have the correction I will update. Thank you! https://github.com/luiscamposjr/cbfm-spring-angular/tree/master/cbfm-web

Comment: You could try ... maybe only for testing ... to add the corresponding OneToMany mapping in the class `Federacao` (... with mappedBy instead JoinColumn)

Comment: I tried it but I have another exception before start de application. I don't no why. I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

The query provided by Meiko is right. I've downloaded your project and found some issues related with the relations of the models.

Don't use the following code,

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_federacao")
@Column(name = "federacao")
public Federacao getFederacao() {
    return federacao;
}
```

But use,

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "federacao")
private Federacao federacao;
```

- Use the name "federacao" instead "id_federacao" because the column you want to join is clubes.federacao and not clubes.id_federacao.
- You can't use @Column with @ManyToOne.

That should solve you're problem. I've also modified some little things, but that shouldn't affect the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my mapping. I just fixed it doing it:

Class Clube

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_federacao", nullable=false)
private Federacao federacao;
```

and Class Federacao

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="federacao")
private Set<Clube> clubes;
```

I have now another problem that I'll post right now.

Thanks everyone.